# Can I store a custom object to the Amazon SQS Listener?

Tags: java, amazon-sqs, pojo

I want to know whether my POJO can be stored in the Amazon SQS rather than the traditional Message object.

Here's the POJO:

```
public class SQSMessage {

    private String id;

    private Long createdTime;

    public SQSMessage() {
    }

    public SQSMessage(String id, Long createdTime) {
        this.id = id;
        this.createdTime = createdTime;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getCreatedTime() {
        return createdTime;
    }

    public void setCreatedTime(Long createdTime) {
        this.createdTime = createdTime;
    }
}
```

If that is not possible, what other ways can you recommend?

Comment: you can transform to JSON then store it. if you wanna save some space, you can zip the JSON and send it to SQS and then unzip on the consumers side

Comment: Zipped binary should be encoded in Base64 to meet Amazon characters restriction: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_SendMessage.html, and this will increase message size at least by 30%.